# dropping rows in a df based condition in the index

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
              A
migeludis     2
sandradsad    3
luislkdksd    4
juandsasdi    5
```

I would like to drop the rows in the df those index  begin with `luis` and `sandra` to obtain this output:

```
              A
migeludis     2
juandsasdi    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and inverse condition by `~`:

```
df = df[~df.index.str.startswith(('luis','sandra'))]
print (df)
            A
migeludis   2
juandsasdi  5
```